# API Call from Shopify's Liquid

Tags: ruby, shopify, liquid, instagram-api

I am writing trying to call the Instagram API from my online store on Shopify. I cannot use javascript because Instagram is not allowing the request. It is not a bad call, or an error, they are just denying it. So, I am using Liquid to call the API.

I am wondering if there is something similar php's curl that I could use with liquid. Does anyone know of such  a thing? Here is what I have so far:

```
{% assign call = endpoint | append: params %}
{{ open(call) }}
```

It is not outputing anything, though I figured it would output a boolean. The "call" variable is indeed correct.

Any help would be great, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As per the first answer, you cannot make direct API calls with liquid. What you need to do is to create a private app proxy that serves as a proxy for the real app that you want to call. Most of the documentation around creating app proxy is for public apps that you sell on the Shopify store, but don't worry, all you need to do is to provide the authentication parameters from when you create a private app to the app proxy and it will work fine.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make API calls with liquid. You'd have to use Shopify's API with your own app (lets say built with PHP) to make these requests. Although, there's no reason why JS shouldn't do the job. I've used http://instafeedjs.com/ before with great success on Shopify themes.

Comment: To elaborate you can't run anything but Liquid server-side on Shopify. Even though it uses Ruby like syntax it's not full Ruby. You either need to proxy your requests through an external server (this is what Apps do) or apply your code client side.

Comment: @nick thats weird, I just tried using instafeed at that is also not working, though I get a different error.